# Redis -- undefined method `SMEMBERS' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I'm building a Rails shopping cart app using Redis. Everything works fine until I try to view my cart, at which point I get this error.

```
NoMethodError in CartsController#show
undefined method `SMEMBERS' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #6):

5  def show
6    cart_ids = $redis.SMEMBERS current_user_cart
7    @order_items = current_order.order_items
8  end
```

The beginning of the full trace:

```
app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:6:in `show'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
```

...and thence through a bunch more behind-the-scenes stuff I haven't touched, mostly activesupport, activerecord, and railties.

Redis-server is installed and responsive; I have tested it with redis-cli.

**Config/initializers/redis.rb:**

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
REDIS = Redis.new(:url => uri)
```

**App/controllers/carts_controller.rb:**

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def show
    cart_ids = $redis.SMEMBERS current_user_cart
    @order_items = current_order.order_items
  end

  def add
    $redis.SADD current_user_cart, params[:product_id]
    render json: current_user.cart_count, status: 200
  end

  def remove
    $redis.SREM current_user_cart, params[:product_id]
    render json: current_user.cart_count, status: 200
  end

    private

  def current_user_cart
    "cart#{current_user.id}"
  end
end
```

The worst part is that I had this problem last week, fixed it, and neglected to write down what the fix was! Anybody have any leads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had two versions of redis installed. I don't know if that was causing the problem, but when I uninstalled both and reinstalled the gem, the problem disappeared!

Answer (score 3):

1. You are using uninitialized global variable `$redis` (look at your `initializers/redis.rb` where you declared constant `REDIS` but not `$redis`)
2. Ruby is case-sensitive language, the `SMEMBERS` and `smembers` are two different methods. So, I think you should use `smembers` method.

Comment: Thank you! I had been using smembers, lowercase, but it gives me the same error message.

Comment: Changing the constant in redis.rb makes sense... now it says

**'uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
$redis = Redis.new(:url => uri)'**

but it still gives me the same error :(